# Why can a swift function declared as needing parameters, be passed without them?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Code written Swift 2.0 on Xcode 7 beta

My question concerns passing functions are parameters. I have two functions: getImagesFromImgur and randomImageHandle. getImagesFromImgur is called at ViewDidLoad like this:

```
self.getImagesFromImgur(apiAction: "gallery.json", 
    handleResponse: self.randomImageHandle)
```

The getImagesFromImgur function looks like this:

```
func getImagesFromImgur(apiAction: String, handleResponse: 
    (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void) {
...

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:
        handleResponse)
...
}
```

The randomImgurHandle that is passed to getImagesFromImgur function in viewDidLoad looks like this:

```
func randomImageHandle(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, 
    error: NSError?) -> Void {
    ...
    //code that edits the UI
    ...
}
```

So my question is, hqow can I pass self.randomImageHandle to self.getImagesFromImgur without specifying any argument values? I know dataTaskWithRequest passes the parameters to the handleResponse, and while I understand that, I'm confused on why the compiler doesn't force me to specify parameters.

EDIT: I'm passing a handle like this so I can have specific handles to match imgur's Api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, functions are first-class types, and you can pass them around as variables. What you're actually doing is that `getImagesFromImgur` is expecting a function that has the exact signature `(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void` (you don't need the Void here, BTW). The compiler checks for you that you passed in a method that has that signature, and thus you don't need to specify parameters.

Comment: If this is kind of hard to understand (it was for me, coming from Java), try reading [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH3-ID0).

Comment: And Swift has an optional "trailing closure syntax" for calling functions where the last parameter is a closure. (The parameter is better called a closure than a function.) In a trailing closure call, you put the closure in braces AFTER the parentheses instead of inside them. It makes the formatting a little easier to read. Search on "trailing closure syntax" in the Apple Swift book ILikeTau mentioned.